# React packager started but not available

Tags: react-native

EDIT : FIXED
The issue was McAfee (anti-virus) blocking the port 8081 by default. I fixed this following this : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10715

Basically, edit the file : react-native/local-cli/server/server.js.

Note : react-native start --port 8088 wasn't working because I needed to launch the app on my device running react-native run-android, which opens a new React Packager on port 8081...

Bellow is the question for reference.

---

I have installed react-packager and try to run the "AwesomeProject" demo app.

After > npm install, I try to call > react-native start. The packager runs normally... But impossible to access the url "localhost:8081" from my browser. What am I doing wrong ?

Details :

> react-native start

```
C:\xxx\zzz\yyy\workspace\front_reactnative>react-native start
(node:9640) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() inste
ad.
Scanning 617 folders for symlinks in C:\xxx\zzz\yyy\workspace\front_
reactnative\node_modules (35ms)
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐

 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │

 │                                                                            │

 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │

 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │

 │  prefer.                                                                   │

 │                                                                            │

 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │

 │                                                                            │

 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   C:\zzz\yyy\xxx\workspace\front_reactnative

[12:34:09] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[12:34:09] <START> Crawling File System
[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.
```

localhost:8081
(or) http://10.0.1.1:8081/

"This page is unavailable"

Comment: Slightly confused at this question - if you're using React Native you should be viewing the project on a mobile device emu by running `react-native run-android` or `run-ios`. By default the demo project should give you a 'Welcome to React Native' type screen. Unless of course you were talking about `react-native-windows`.

Comment: On the emulator/android device I had the error message "Packager not started" - or something like that. From the computer, I can access to the Packager with localhost. Long story short, the port 8081 was blocked by McAfee. What I did is change the default port of React Packager by 8088, then it works (check Google/Bing/Yahoo/Lycos to change the default port, it's in a configuration file inside react-native folder...)